# Problems accessing and using response status code after first then() in Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, es6-promise

As outlined in the title, i'm trying to use the response status code which is available in the first `then` alongside the JSON response data, but at a later stage in the promise. But instead getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0`

promise snippet:

```
 //fetch request
 .then((res) =>
      //can access status code here
      res.json().then((data) => ({ status: res.status, sid: data.sid }))
    )
    .then((data) => {
      // status code undefined 
      if (data.status === 401) {
        setShowError(true);
        setErrorMessage("Your email and/or password is incorrect.");
      } else if (data.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem("_sid", data.sid);
        history.push("/");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

express route snippet:

```
if (user) {
        req.session.userID = user._id;
        res.status(200).json({ sid: req.session.id });
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
      }
    }
```

Comment: your promise chaining logic is incorrect.

Comment: The error indicates that the resource your are fetching from is not returning JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Your promise chaining logic is incorrect as it is not returning a promise from first then block.

Try chaining it like this -

```
//fetch request
 .then((res) => res.json())
 .then((data) => ({ status: res.status, sid: data.sid }))
 .then((data) => {
      // status code undefined 
      if (data.status === 401) {
        setShowError(true);
        setErrorMessage("Your email and/or password is incorrect.");
      } else if (data.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem("_sid", data.sid);
        history.push("/");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```